# Reading from user-defined Table Types

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a scenario where i have to store & send my Datatable from UI  to sql server. For that i have created one table type for which definition is like below.

```
  CREATE TYPE AllocationDt AS TABLE
  (
    Healthplan VARCHAR(MAX),
    Site VARCHAR(MAX),
    TotaMembers VARCHAR(MAX),
    EarnedPeriod VARCHAR(MAX),
    PMPM VARCHAR(MAX),
    TOtalAmount NVARCHAR(MAX),
    HealthPlanID NVARCHAR(MAX),
    SiteID NVARCHAR(MAX),
    TempEffDate NVARCHAR(MAX),
    TempTermDate NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
```

Passing it like this from DAL:

```
objDB.AddInParameter(objCMD, "@dtAllocation", SqlDbType.Structured, dtAllocation);
```

While executing i'm having an error:

```
Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.
```

Any one knows the root cause behind this?

Comment: I would strongly suggest you go back and look closer at the datatypes you choose. nvarchar(max) for everything is truly horrible. Some of these are dates, other seem to be numbers. Use the proper datatypes. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Comment: That's not an issue i guess. it was modified by me for testing purpose only. @SeanLange

Comment: OK, but wouldn't it make more sense to use the correct type for testing? Unless this is just a proof of concept that kind of thing is a slippery slope. Can you share some of your code? A single line is really not very helpful. Where do you define dtAllocation? What is it? Is it a datatable? Does it have rows? Are the columns named correctly to fill your table type?

Comment: In which line exactly the error occurred? You should put snippets inside the method where the exception thrown. I can't make sure that the issue is coming from your TVP/table valued parameter, but you should check against `DBNull.Value` before doing conversion.